# Unity Multiplayer client inputs are invaild

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity-networking, unity3d-unet

I try to do football game for fun but i got a problem

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "BallTAG")
        RpcAddForceToBall(other.gameObject);

}
[ClientRpc]
public void RpcAddForceToBall(GameObject hit)
{
        if (Input.GetButton("Drag"))
        {
            hit.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce((movement * 200) * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Shoot"))
            hit.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce((new Vector3(movement.x, 0.60f, movement.z) * 2000 * PlayerCC.velocity.magnitude) * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

host can drag or shoot  but client can't do something to ball.
but if i do like that

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    hit.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(10,10,10);
    if (other.tag == "BallTAG")
        RpcAddForceToBall(other.gameObject);

}
```

client can do force to ball

also i do that too

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log("Entered");
    if (Input.GetButton("Drag"))
        Debug.Log("Dragging");

}
```

still can print Entered on Client but dragging isn't host can print both of them

What can i do for fix that?

Comment: This wold likely get more traction on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: "client can do force to ball" is this happening on different client also?